# How to solve no file error when unzip files in R?

Tags: r, data-cleaning, unzip

### **1. Problems I met**

A very strange error occurred to me these days. I wrote a loop to extract hundreds of zip files in my disk. Things work good initially but it will stuck at some point and report an error message like:

```
> extractResult <- extract(zipDir="/home/rstudio/Nick/00.Viscosity Modeling/Data")
Extracting  1 / 383  batch:  F-171204-00040 --- *INVALID*
Extracting  2 / 383  batch:  F-171207-00005 --- *INVALID*
Extracting  3 / 383  batch:  F-171211-00005.1 --- *INVALID*
......
Extracting  56 / 383  batch:  F-180621-00039 --- *INVALID*
Extracting  57 / 383  batch:  F-180621-00043 --- :)

Error in unzip(zips, exdir = to_dir) : 
  cannot open file '/home/rstudio/Nick/00.Viscosity Modeling/Data/Extract/F-180625-00014/Material.csv': No such file or directory
In addition: Warning messages:
```

Then I try to unzip this file separately but this same error occurs and occurs. So I tried to unzip another file `F-180621-00043.zip` which was successfully unzipped, but the most weired thing is it cannot be exrtacted, same for all the zip files listed above:

```
    > unzip("/home/rstudio/Nick/00.Viscosity Modeling/Data/archive/F-180621-00043.zip"
           ,exdir="/home/rstudio/Nick/00.Viscosity Modeling/Data")

    Error in unzip("/home/rstudio/Nick/00.Viscosity Modeling/Data/archive/F-180621-00043.zip",  : 
       cannot open file '/home/rstudio/Nick/00.Viscosity Modeling/Data/F-180621-00043/Material.csv':
       No such file or directory
```

My first thought is these files are corrupted so I added the `list` attribute, but it looks they are ready to be unzipped:

```
    > unzip("/home/rstudio/Nick/00.Viscosity Modeling/Data/archive/F-180621-00043.zip"
           ,exdir="/home/rstudio/Nick/00.Viscosity Modeling/Data",list=T)

                             Name   Length                Date
    1 F-180621-00043/Material.csv     6486 2020-04-24 06:30:00
    2  F-180621-00043/Quality.csv      330 2020-04-24 06:30:00
    3   F-180621-00043/Sensor.csv 93801262 2020-04-24 06:30:00
```

### **2. So my question is:**

1. there are csv fils in my zip but `R` keeps reporting there is no such file, why?
2. why those files are extracted normally in my loop but cannot be unzipped by one-line `unzip` function?

Can anybody help me sort this error?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!!!**

I forgot to mention that all of the work I was doing is based on R Server, i.e. I'm working on the cloud.

It seems our company only provided us a limited cloud space for RStudio, so this error has no relation with `unzip` or my `zip files`. The unzip will stop once my allocated server is unable to store any `byte` of files.

Hope this will help some other people met similar problems.